# How to use a switch statement in a widget class

Tags: dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to display a container with some designs if it gets some data from firestore but if there is no data from firestore I want it to show a text saying `no data from firestore`, but it is not working and I'm getting errors.
...............................................................................................................................

below is the code, is this correct? `getStoriesFunction`:

```
 Widget _getStories() {
    Live users;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: getStory(users),
    );
  }

Widget getStory(Live user) {
    return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            user.isLive == true
                ? Container(
                    height: 55,
                    width: 55,
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        // Join function
                        onJoin(
                            channelName: user.displayName,
                            channelId: user.channelId,
                            displayName: displayName,
                            hostImage: user.image,
                            userImage: image);
                      },
                      child: Stack(
                        alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            height: 60,
                            width: 60,
                            child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [
                                        Colors.red,
                                        Colors.redAccent,
                                        Colors.red
                                      ],
                                      begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                      end: Alignment.bottomRight)),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                            height: 55.5,
                            width: 55.5,
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                          CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: user.image,
                            imageBuilder: (context, imageProvider) => Container(
                              width: 52.0,
                              height: 52.0,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: imageProvider, fit: BoxFit.cover),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Container(
                              height: 70,
                              width: 70,
                              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                              child: Stack(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Container(
                                    height: 17,
                                    width: 25,
                                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                      shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(
                                              4.0) //         <--- border radius here
                                          ),
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                          colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black],
                                          begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          end: Alignment.centerRight),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Container(
                                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                        shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                            Radius.circular(
                                                2.0) //         <--- border radius here
                                            ),
                                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                                            colors: [
                                              Colors.red,
                                              Colors.redAccent
                                            ],
                                            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                            end: Alignment.centerRight),
                                      ),
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                        child: Text(
                                          'LIVE',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 7,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      )),
                                ],
                              ))
                        ],
                      ),
                    ))
                : Text('No data in firestore',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      fontSize: 12,
                    ))
          ],
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Yes your code is fine. For List data, you can use Future/StreamBuilder as per your need.

Comment: ok sure, will try that out and get back to you. Thanks @Deepakswain

Comment: Hi, any ideas on how to use the Future/StreamBuilder? @Deepakswain

Answer (score 0):

I have corrected you code and tested in the [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/dart) and work well for me. You can test to just copy and pase. It something wrong with user data from the firebase looks like `bool isLive`  always true.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  // Fake user data
  bool userExist = false;

  void _toggleUserState() {
    setState(() => userExist = !userExist);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _getStories(userExist),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _toggleUserState,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _getStories(bool user) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: getStory(user),
    );
  }

  Widget getStory(bool user) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(12),
      child: user == true
          ? Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: 55,
                  width: 55,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      // Join function
                      print('Join Function');
                    },
                    child: Stack(
                      alignment: Alignment(0, 0),
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 60,
                          width: 60,
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.red,
                                    Colors.redAccent,
                                    Colors.red
                                  ],
                                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomRight),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 55.5,
                          width: 55.5,
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          ),
                        ),
                        // Cached Image container here.
                        Container(
                          height: 55.5,
                          width: 55.5,
                          child: Text('Cached Image'),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          height: 70,
                          width: 70,
                          alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          child: Stack(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                height: 17,
                                width: 25,
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(4.0),
                                  ),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black],
                                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      end: Alignment.centerRight),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2.0)),
                                  gradient: LinearGradient(
                                      colors: [Colors.red, Colors.redAccent],
                                      begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                      end: Alignment.centerRight),
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    'LIVE',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 7,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          : Text(
              'No data in firestore',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 12,
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Woow, that's awesome. I noticed that you made a function called `void _toggleUserState()` and in it you added a `setState()` function. Why?

Comment: I added it just to show you that code work and setState was simplest way to rebuild state.

Comment: ok, it's great to know that I can use `setState` but because of how large my project is, I decided to use the `StreamBuilder`.